# Excel cell format - date notaton

Tags: c#, excel, date, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where I define a date like: `DD/MM/YYYY`. When I export my date with the use of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` functionalities, Excel automatically recognizes this as a date format, but not in the way I want it. My solution:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range dateColumn = mySheet.get_Range("E1").EntrireColumn;
dateColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@";
```

The funny thing is that, this is working within Excel 2007 professional. When I deploy the application on a PC with Excel 2010 basic, it is not working anymore. The language settings of both Excel versions is English (U.S. standard). This can't be a feature of basic VS. professional right?

Comment: Probably you should write `=` on the first line, not `-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this so long ago, I cannot remember all the reasoning behind it but here is what I use:

```
public static void ChangeDateFormat(Excel.Range cell, string format, bool useLocale)
{
    if (useLocale && !format.Contains("[$"))
    {
        format = "[$-800]" + format;
    }        
    SetProperty(cell, "NumberFormatLocal", new object[] { format });        
}


public static void SetProperty(object target, string name, params object[] args)
{
    target.GetType().InvokeMember(name,
        BindingFlags.SetProperty |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, target, args, new CultureInfo(1033));
}
```