# Dates being flipped through inter op excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am having a strange issue with dates in excel at present some dates when exported from my grid while displaying file are swapping the month and days however I used the number format to account for this but still some items seems to have an issue.

```
private static void ExportToExcel(List<ListViewItem> items, ListView listView)
{
        using (var progressIndicatorForm = new ProgressIndicatorForm(0, items.Count))
        {
            try
            {
                progressIndicatorForm.Show();
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = null;

                try
                {
                    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    workBook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
                    workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[1];

                    List<string> columnNames = GetColumnNames(listView);

                    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnNames.Count; columnIndex++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[0 + 1, columnIndex + 1] = columnNames[columnIndex];
                    }

                    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= items.Count; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        progressIndicatorForm.Current = rowIndex;
                        progressIndicatorForm.Description = string.Format("Exporting {0} of {1} records...", rowIndex, items.Count);
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

                        var item = items[rowIndex - 1];

                        for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < listView.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
                        {
                            var column = listView.Columns[columnIndex];

                            if (column.Tag != null && column.Tag.ToString() == typeof(DateTime).ToString())
                            {
                                string text = item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text;

                                DateTime? dateTime = ParseDateTime(text);

                                if (dateTime.HasValue)
                                {
                                    Range range = (Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1];
                                    range.Value = dateTime.Value.ToOADate();
                                    range.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    workSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1] = text;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                workSheet.Cells[rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1] = item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    app.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionManager.HandleUnexpectedException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    app = null;
                    workBook = null;
                    workSheet = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.HandleUnexpectedException(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                progressIndicatorForm.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you see I am using the following which is the suggested method for the dd/mm/yyyy

> range.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

Comment: `ParseDateTime(text);` What is the **exact** value of `text` (please debug, don't guess)? Please show us the source code for `ParseDateTime` (since the bug is in there).

Comment: Use OLEDB or ODBC for data tasks and you would be good.

Comment: im stuck using interop old program cant make major change

Comment: why has this been downvoted this is a valid question no commentry has been given as to why it was downvoted

Comment: I didn't do the downvote - but it could be because you don't show us enough information to help you - seeing the actual date strings from _"item.SubItems[columnIndex].Text"_ would help as would the body of the _"ParseDateTime"_. Without either of those we are just guessing. Do you know for sure the date in the text string is valid & hasn't been entered as mm/dd/yyyy? Is it consistently going wrong or is it just particular dates.

Comment: It may be worth seeing if setting _"NumberFormatLocal"_ rather than _"NumberFormat"_ resolves the problem. Rather complex way of setting here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184580/excel-cell-format-date-notaton  - _"range.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/MM/yyyy";"_ is simpler. Or set both.

Comment: Are you able to share `ParseDateTime` with us?